# how to save image after editing in php

Tags: php, html, css, image

i have a image and i wrote some text on this image by using php "imagettftext" function. now i don't know that how it will save automatic.

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
// Create the image
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('image-1.jpg');

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
//imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// The text to draw
$text = 'www.blockprintsonline.com';

// Replace path by your own font path
$font = 'arial.ttf';

list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($get_image);
$width1=$width*20/100;
$height1=$height*50/100;
$font_size=$width*4/100;

// Add some shadow to the text
//imagettftext($im, 30, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, $font_size, 0, $width1, $height1, $black, $font, $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save the image to a file, check out the docs for the `imagepng()` function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php).

By passing a filename as the second argument it will save the image to a file, e.g:

```
imagepng($im, "path/to/save/image/in.png");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

// Save the image as 'simpletext.png'
imagepng($im, 'simpletext.png');

// Free up memory
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

this is an example on how to save an image.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the documentation for [imagepng](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php) you would see that you can provide a filename. That would save the image to disk